# Google scripts search with manual "next result" option

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

i am building script in Google Spreadsheet that can find multiple results (like range of given dates) and then first display first result that script find. I need to show me how many results there is (like 'result 1/4') and that i have another button for 'next result'

i have a list in one sheet with numbers:

```
3
5
45
3
77
```

i wanted to search another sheet and when script find that row i wanted to copy to another sheet but only that row. So in first run it will copy row 3, in second run it will copy row 5 etc.

i have script that find and copy row based on one value but i wanted to modify it to search for multiple result and display it one by one (like button Next result)

```
    function Get(){

  //gets and formats data ranges, to and from sheets.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Base_NG");
var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Radni_sheet");
var ID = target_sheet.getRange("E2"); 
var searchString = ID.getValue();
var column =1; //column Index   
var columnValues = source_sheet.getRange(2, column, source_sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //1st is header row
var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex(searchString); //Row Index - 2



     if 

      (target_sheet.getRange('E2').getValue() == "") {
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('ID nije upisan!')}

  else {




  //funkcija traženja po ID-u

    if(searchResult != -1)
    {
        //searchResult + 2 is row index.
      var values_search = source_sheet.getRange(searchResult + 2, 3).getValues();



        //if function find result it will copy here



 CODE for copy






    }}

}

//loop 
Array.prototype.findIndex = function(search){
  if(search == "") return false;
  for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++)
    if (this[i].toString().indexOf(search) > -1 ) return i;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('ID ne postoji');
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Radni_sheet");
  target_sheet.getRange('E3:E18').clearContent(); 

  return -1;
```